# Access Denied in IIS

Tags: c#, iis

I have a web application deployed on IIS.

When my Web Application is trying to move file from A location to B location it is giving below error,
"System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path"

Also,
Access Denied is faced for folder "D:\FileMove\SomeFolder_1"
But it is not faced for folder "D:\FileMove\SomeFolder_2"

Both folder are inside "FileMove" then why issue it is access denied for one folder

Comment: Check your destination folder's permissions.

Comment: do you use anonymous authentication?

Comment: Run `icacls D:\FileMove\SomeFolder_1` and `icacls D:\FileMove\SomeFolder_2` at command prompt and compare the output first.

Comment: Hi Davis Jahn, yes we are using anonymous authentication.

Comment: Hi Berkay, if it is destination folder's permissions issue then why from one folder we are able to move both are inside same parent directory

Comment: Hi Lex Li, is there any way to check file permissions because some file are moving but for few files access denied error is been faced

Answer (score 3):

go to application pool check the app pool identity and set needed permissions to D:\FileMove\ for that user

Answer (score 1):

How to set permission on the folder in IIS for .net Apps.

[image: Internet Information Server]

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you didn't set permissions for the user.
set the permissions and it should run fine.

Comment: If there is an permission issue, then why some files are moving?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the iis_iusrs and iusr full control permission to the D:\FileMove folder. and make sure the replace all child object permission checkbox is checked.

[image]

if you still face issues then try to use the process monitor to capture the permission for the D:\FileMove folder.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Hi, I have one doubt the folder from where file i moving have default pool permission. And the folder from where it is not moving does not have that user permission. Please let me know why other other is not having that permission

Comment: could you please share which permission that folder have? for troubleshooting about permission, the best way is to use the process monitor. look like that folder has another permission so you could access it easily but the moving folder does not have enough read or write permission.

Comment: The folders from where files are moving have defaultAppPool user with special permission

Comment: @metaphor did you tried to use the process monitor?